# Problemas para importar la libreria Jgrapht en un proyecto de netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

consulto por aquí por si alguien más ha tenido este problema y ha encontrado solución, he descargado desde la pagina oficial de [jgrapht](http://jgrapht.org/) el archivo zip que tienen, para windows, luego trato de importar en mi netbeans la libreria haciendo click derecho en la libreria y luego "agregar archivo JAR/carpeta" añade el archivo sin problemas con un montón de paquetes.

El problema esta en que luego por más que recompile, es como si no hubiera importado nada, es decir, al escribir [el código de ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246409/how-to-inlcude-weight-in-edge-of-graph)

no me reconoce ni me deja importar

```
import org.jgrapht.*;
import org.jgrapht.alg.*;
import org.jgrapht.graph.*;
```

He tratado de hacerlo a mano, pero el problema es que si importo a mano por ejemplo el core, algunas cosas como el `DijkstraShortestPath.findPathBetween` no funciona correctamente como aparece en el la documentación oficial de jgrapht si no como si fuera una versión antigua y la verdad ya no se que más hacer, si alguien sabe que puedo hacer para que se importe correctamente se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Utilizas Maven o gradle para agregar referencias a tu proyecto ? Puede ser algo tan sencillo como agregar la referencia de la librería o la dependencia. Lo menciono porque tuve experiencia con eclipse y no solo basta con copiar el .jar, dependiendo de la configuración y el tipo de proyecto necesitas agregar lo que te menciono. Recuerdo que en el classpath del proyecto agregas el jar para mantener una referencia al archivo físico.

Comment: Actualmente no utilizo Maven o Gradle, ya que la verdad uso más que nada netbeans para los trabajos de la uned donde por lo general no hace falta muchas bibliotecas externas o ya estan incluidas así que hasta ahora no he tenido que hacer más que añadirlas como ya indique antes, por eso estoy tan perdido y pegado en este tema.

Entonces me recomiendas añadir el jar al classpath ¿no? ¿si no funcionara deberia probar con Maven o gradle?

Comment: Maven o gradle te ayudan a mejorar y compilar librerías y dependencias del proyecto. Tienen varias funcionalidades pero no es necesario. Y pues sí agrega el jar al classpath y eso debería de ayudarte a que se reconozcan las clases en su proyecto. Si no es la solución avise a ver que podemos hacer

Comment: He seguido los pasos que indica en este tutorial para añadir una biblioteca java en el classpath sin exito, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598623/how-to-setup-classpath-in-netbeans

Comment: Sin embargo el problema es el mismo, no reconoce el contenido, o no es capaz de aplicarlo, he intentado con maven, añadiendo la dependencia, pero es aún peor porque aparecen errores diferentes en este caso, me permite hacer los imports, sin embargo deja de reconocer la variable graph https://prnt.sc/hpmtet me he fijado no se si sera importante o no que aparece con un candado las librerias, no se si sera algo importante o no.

Ya por ultimo me estoy planteando no se si seria una buena idea desinstalar netbeans y java y resinstalar todo, porque me estoy volviendo loco.

Comment: Dame un chance, voy a bajar netbeans y lo pruebo a ver como era que funcionaba.

Comment: dices que estas haciendolo con un archivo zip, por que no intentas descomprimiendo y solo agregando los .jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que hice para ver si es un problema general del IDE fue crear mi proyecto e importar todos los jar.

Le das clic derecho sobre la carpeta Libraries:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente seleccioné todos los .jar y listo. Los .jars estan en la carpeta después de comprimir el .zip. Lo que hice fue irme al folder del proyecto y crear una carpeta llamada libs ahí deje todos los .jars y de ahí mismo estoy agregando las referencias al proyecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para finalizar el proyecto queda algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para probar una clase hice a importar Graph y este se importa bien.

Espero que sea de ayuda. Saludos!